# Proving continuity of the following function

Tags: general-topology, analysis, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$  be compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the usual topology) and  let $f:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R }$ be a continues function function

moreover let $P(Y)$ be the space of all probabilities on $Y$ with the weak topology.

How can we show that the following function is continues?

$F:X\times P(Y) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined as $F(x,p)=E_p[f(x,y)]$?

Comment: looks like you need a topology or a metric on $P(Y)$, do you have one?

Comment: shouldn't it be F: X x Y into R? I don't see how the set of probability measures on Y contains an argument for the function F?

Comment: @user66081, I edited

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman , no because $F$ gets a probability on $Y$

Comment: oh ok I was focusing on the RHS and ignoring the LHS. got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \to x$ and $p_n \Rightarrow p$, where the second denotes weak convergence.

To show:
$$\int_Y f(x_n, y) dp_n(y) \to \int_Y f(x, y) dp(y).$$

Since $X \times Y$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous. So $\sup_{y \in Y}|f(x_n, y) - f(x, y)| \leq \epsilon$ may be assumed.

Then we have (using that the total mass is one)
$$
\left|\int_Y f(x_n, y) dp_n(y) - \int_Y f(x, y) dp(y)\right| \leq \left|\int_Y f(x, y) dp_n(y) - \int_Y f(x, y) dp(y)\right| + \epsilon
.
$$

The first expression on the right goes to zero by weak convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this follow from the fact that the expectation is a bounded (hence continuous) linear functional for probability measures on compact spaces?

Answer (score 1):

$E_p[f(x,y)]-E_{p^*}[f(x^*,y)]=(E_p[f(x,y)]-E_{p^*}[f(x,y)])+(E_{p^*}[f(x,y)]-E_{p^*}[f(x^*,y)])$

As $p^*\rightarrow p$ weakly, the first term converges to $0$, since you take the expectation of a given bounded continuous function. The second term is less than $\sup_{y}|f(x,y)-f(x^*,y)|$, which, by the compactness and the continuity of $f$, also converges to $0$ as $x^*\rightarrow x.$